# Android CTS test - test_execCreatedJar failing

Tags: android, android-cts

I'm trying to debug this test which is failing on our device while it works within the emulator. The test generates a .jar file and will try to extract the .dex and run the same. I debugged the call stack and found that in the emulator, the sequence is different. I see these prints (the 1st two lines are mine):

E/dalvikvm(  754): HV: Dalvik_dalvik_system_DexFile_openDexFile, Might call dvmJarFileOpen for '/data/data/android.core.tests.runner/cache/cts_dalvikExecTest_41998785.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  754): HV: dvmJarFileOpen, Calling dvmOptimizeDexFile for '/data/data/android.core.tests.runner/cache/cts_dalvikExecTest_41998785.jar'
D/dalvikvm(  754): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'cts_dalvikExecTest_41998785.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
D/dalvikvm(  754): DexOpt: --- END 'cts_dalvikExecTest_41998785.jar' (success) ---
D/dalvikvm(  754): DEX prep '/data/data/android.core.tests.runner/cache/cts_dalvikExecTest_41998785.jar': unzip in 1ms, rewrite 204ms

On my device, I don't see any of the above prints. Any ideas how I can debug further?

Thanks
HV

Comment: Which test are you trying yo debug?

Comment: That is the entire command:run cts --c libcore.java.util.jar.DalvikExecTest -m test_execCreatedJar

Comment: I understand, sorry for bothering.

Comment: Found that if I increase the timeout value, the test passes. I guess DVM is running a little slow on our platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the timeout is the solution